# Post to a aspx site, and return and view xml in android app

Tags: java, android

im trying to make a simple android app. I want to post a request to [this](http://timeplan.uia.no/swsuiagrv/public/no/default.aspx) aspx site.I have a list the users picks a choice from. When the user chooce a listitem, I want to have an if statement that inputs the correct post variables to the site. I assume I have to use some kind of http post package. When the post is sent I want to return the xml that the site gives the http_post and show it to the user.

How would I go about this? I cant seem to find any way to show the result to the user. And I'm unsure if this is the best approach.

Is there a simpler way? Originally i thought of something like offer the user a simple WebView with a unique link to each item in the form list. But I'm unable to create independent direct links due to that annyoing .aspx server-side handling.

Could anyone help me out? :)